# athena create view from another database table through aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-glue, amazon-athena

aws cli for creating view from another database table.

```
aws athena start-query-execution --query-string "create or replace view view_table_name as select column1, column2 from "anotherDateBaseName".tableName" --work-group "workgroupName" --query-execution-context Database=databaseName,Catalog=awsCatalogName
```

tried the above code and is giving error InvalidRequestException

Answer (score 0):

use the below code for create view from cli from another table

```
aws athena start-query-execution --query-string "create or replace view view_table_name as select column1, column2 from \"anotherDateBaseName\".tableName" --work-group "workgroupName" --query-execution-context Database=databaseName,Catalog=awsCatalogName
```